# I want to make panorama image but it is showing the error message Undefined function 'imageSet' for input arguments of type 'char'

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-guide, matlab-cvst

Undefined function 'imageSet' for input arguments of type 'char'.

Error in build (line 3)
buildingScene = imageSet(buildingDir);

```
% Load images.
buildingDir = fullfile(toolboxdir('vision'), 'visiondata', 'building');
buildingScene = imageSet(buildingDir);
% Display images to be stitched
montage(buildingScene.ImageLocation)
% Read the first image from the image set.
I = read(buildingScene, 1);
% Initialize features for I(1)
grayImage = rgb2gray(I);
points = detectSURFFeatures(grayImage);
[features, points] = extractFeatures(grayImage, points);

% Initialize all the transforms to the identity matrix. Note that the
% projective transform is used here because the building images are fairly
% close to the camera. Had the scene been captured from a further distance,
% an affine transform would suffice.
tforms(buildingScene.Count) = projective2d(eye(3));

% Iterate over remaining image pairs
for n = 2:buildingScene.Count

    % Store points and features for I(n-1).
    pointsPrevious = points;
    featuresPrevious = features;

    % Read I(n).
    I = read(buildingScene, n);

    % Detect and extract SURF features for I(n).
    grayImage = rgb2gray(I);
    points = detectSURFFeatures(grayImage);
    [features, points] = extractFeatures(grayImage, points);

    % Find correspondences between I(n) and I(n-1).
    indexPairs = matchFeatures(features, featuresPrevious, 'Unique', true);

    matchedPoints = points(indexPairs(:,1), :);
    matchedPointsPrev = pointsPrevious(indexPairs(:,2), :);

    % Estimate the transformation between I(n) and I(n-1).
    tforms(n) = estimateGeometricTransform(matchedPoints, matchedPointsPrev,...
        'projective', 'Confidence', 99.9, 'MaxNumTrials', 2000);

    % Compute T(1) * ... * T(n-1) * T(n)
    tforms(n).T = tforms(n-1).T * tforms(n).T;
end
avgXLim = mean(xlim, 2);

[~, idx] = sort(avgXLim);

centerIdx = floor((numel(tforms)+1)/2);

centerImageIdx = idx(centerIdx);
Tinv = invert(tforms(centerImageIdx));

for i = 1:numel(tforms)
    tforms(i).T = Tinv.T * tforms(i).T;
end
for i = 1:numel(tforms)
    [xlim(i,:), ylim(i,:)] = outputLimits(tforms(i), [1 imageSize(2)], [1 imageSize(1)]);
end

% Find the minimum and maximum output limits
xMin = min([1; xlim(:)]);
xMax = max([imageSize(2); xlim(:)]);

yMin = min([1; ylim(:)]);
yMax = max([imageSize(1); ylim(:)]);

% Width and height of panorama.
width  = round(xMax - xMin);
height = round(yMax - yMin);

% Initialize the "empty" panorama.
panorama = zeros([height width 3], 'like', I);
Step 4 - Create the Panorama

Use imwarp to map images into the panorama and use vision.AlphaBlender to overlay the images together.

blender = vision.AlphaBlender('Operation', 'Binary mask', ...
    'MaskSource', 'Input port');

% Create a 2-D spatial reference object defining the size of the panorama.
xLimits = [xMin xMax];
yLimits = [yMin yMax];
panoramaView = imref2d([height width], xLimits, yLimits);

% Create the panorama.
for i = 1:buildingScene.Count

    I = read(buildingScene, i);

    % Transform I into the panorama.
    warpedImage = imwarp(I, tforms(i), 'OutputView', panoramaView);

    % Create an mask for the overlay operation.
    warpedMask = imwarp(ones(size(I(:,:,1))), tforms(i), 'OutputView', panoramaView);

    % Clean up edge artifacts in the mask and convert to a binary image.
    warpedMask = warpedMask >= 1;

    % Overlay the warpedImage onto the panorama.
    panorama = step(blender, panorama, warpedImage, warpedMask);
end

figure
imshow(panorama)
```

Comment: % Load images.
buildingDir = fullfile(toolboxdir('vision'), 'visiondata', 'building');
buildingScene = imageSet(buildingDir);
% Display images to be stitched
montage(buildingScene.ImageLocation)
% Read the first image from the image set.
I = read(buildingScene, 1);
% Initialize features for I(1)
grayImage = rgb2gray(I);
points = detectSURFFeatures(grayImage);
[features, points] = extractFeatures(grayImage, points);

Comment: The function `imageSet` requires the `Computer Vision Toolbox`...so it looks like you don't have it. What do you get when you type `which imageSet` in the Command Window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageSet` requires the Computer Vision Toolbox from MATLAB R2014b or higher.  See the release notes from the Computer Vision Toolbox here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/release-notes.html#R2014b

If you have R2014a or lower, `imageSet` does not come with your distribution.  The only option you have is to upgrade your MATLAB distribution.  Sorry if this isn't what you wanted to hear!

Comment: Mr Rayryeng thanks a lot for helping me ,I installed  Matlab 2015.
I created a folder and put 3 photos on it and named it buildingScene , but after run it others photos showed instead of my photos, and these errors showed:

Comment: Warning: Image is too big to fit on screen; displaying at 33% 
> In images.internal.initSize (line 71)
  In imshow (line 305)
  In montage (line 152)
  In Untitled (line 5) 
Attempted to access idx(3); index out of bounds because numel(idx)=1.

Error in Untitled (line 53)
centerImageIdx = idx(centerIdx);
 
>> imshow
Error using imshow>preParseInputs (line 421)
IMSHOW expected at least 1 input argument but was called instead with 0 input arguments.

Error in imshow (line 214)
  varargin_translated = preParseInputs(varargin{:});